# ¿Como recorro una array Json ? y extraigo un valor especifico

Tags: php, json, array

El código es el siguiente:

```
  {  
  "ok":true,
  "result":{  
     "total_count":10,
     "photos":[  
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADyKcxG2fzJBevk8tOwCpnuY8AAQswAAS5FWhCNSvhf39MAgABAg",
              "file_size":14121,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADyKcxG2fzJBevk8tOwCpnuY8AAQswAAQFvpM-NxlHMoBMAgABAg",
              "file_size":44240,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADyKcxG2fzJBevk8tOwCpnuY8AAQswAAQwCWeX2xsWvIFMAgABAg",
              "file_size":131464,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADx6cxG2fzJBczDLnvCwABK3n4cQwwAARwmzHH04Pg5vBbAwABAg",
              "file_size":13986,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADx6cxG2fzJBczDLnvCwABK3n4cQwwAAR1wBtIIyQ8gfFbAwABAg",
              "file_size":43667,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADx6cxG2fzJBczDLnvCwABK3n4cQwwAAQB7SsLcIovIPJbAwABAg",
              "file_size":129783,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADxqcxG2fzJBcPGd6XVP3GErAZFDAABNnQowUi8XHPNcMAAgI",
              "file_size":13978,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADxqcxG2fzJBcPGd6XVP3GErAZFDAABA8c8hgTk_LqNsMAAgI",
              "file_size":44266,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADxqcxG2fzJBcPGd6XVP3GErAZFDAABDBu0q-HHAtcN8MAAgI",
              "file_size":133055,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtqcxG2fzJBfIJ8uP5OSdNCm-CjAABC-k3Hv7H2EXrMAAAgI",
              "file_size":12967,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtqcxG2fzJBfIJ8uP5OSdNCm-CjAABLvQS3K_RTlTrcAAAgI",
              "file_size":34790,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtqcxG2fzJBfIJ8uP5OSdNCm-CjAABJheLz-2o164rsAAAgI",
              "file_size":92836,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtKcxG2fzJBfacbvzlSjBqqT7CjAABCfDugQ729C1zjAAAgI",
              "file_size":10797,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtKcxG2fzJBfacbvzlSjBqqT7CjAABNQPokcjjeSezzAAAgI",
              "file_size":23675,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADtKcxG2fzJBfacbvzlSjBqqT7CjAABIIVZePI8gcX0DAAAgI",
              "file_size":66848,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADs6cxG2fzJBc6sK4kodLKmD4lAzAABA1mjPdNwCMoqpECAAEC",
              "file_size":9704,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADs6cxG2fzJBc6sK4kodLKmD4lAzAABOnq4glL5Dixq5ECAAEC",
              "file_size":21532,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADs6cxG2fzJBc6sK4kodLKmD4lAzAABGNNGkHUes9mrJECAAEC",
              "file_size":59863,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsqcxG2fzJBfEfOpUKWgkmFpoAzAABE0yohMUX4famXUAAgI",
              "file_size":9399,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsqcxG2fzJBfEfOpUKWgkmFpoAzAABGIatU2IXUwBmnUAAgI",
              "file_size":25409,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsqcxG2fzJBfEfOpUKWgkmFpoAzAABFnFUmhgtvR7m3UAAgI",
              "file_size":73639,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsKcxG2fzJBczG743DI4JXvosAzAABP8xEnFlL1Y2oWsCAAEC",
              "file_size":9477,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsKcxG2fzJBczG743DI4JXvosAzAABFWCVFULlJCdomsCAAEC",
              "file_size":20839,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADsKcxG2fzJBczG743DI4JXvosAzAABI5SmM4oZGeKo2sCAAEC",
              "file_size":58965,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADrqcxG2fzJBd2kMrXqt_iSsFzDDAABH6R1MoQduKhB4EBAAEC",
              "file_size":10611,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADrqcxG2fzJBd2kMrXqt_iSsFzDDAABEhHlyT8HwZ_CIEBAAEC",
              "file_size":22798,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADrqcxG2fzJBd2kMrXqt_iSsFzDDAABOTQuongkGnaCYEBAAEC",
              "file_size":59571,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ],
        [  
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADqacxG2fzJBcKJFvxgDeXd264CjAABBbtFH1kxSiAxREAAgI",
              "file_size":6943,
              "width":160,
              "height":160
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADqacxG2fzJBcKJFvxgDeXd264CjAABHygb4oena7_xhEAAgI",
              "file_size":17946,
              "width":320,
              "height":320
           },
           {  
              "file_id":"AgADAQADqacxG2fzJBcKJFvxgDeXd264CjAABDLjXMgan3EIxxEAAgI",
              "file_size":44860,
              "width":640,
              "height":640
           }
        ]
     ]
  }
}
```

es en una web ya la codifique

```
$resultado = file_get_contents($url)
$resultado = json_decode($resultado, TRUE)
```

El problema es que quisiera recorrer la array "photos" y obtener el file_id de cada uno
al intentar hacer

```
foreach ($resultado as $clave => $valor){
  send($clave, $valor);
}
```

me envia

```
ok true
result total_count
photos Array
```

La funcion send($clave, $valor) es la siguiente:

```
function send($clave, $valor){
  print $clave => $valor
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para acceder a las photos, que estan en un array de arrays, debes hacer más foreach.
Lo que hacemos es llegar hasta photos, añadiendo las keys para ir metiendose dentro del array `$resultado['result']['photos']`, ahora nuestro $valor es un array con los datos de una sola foto, la cual se ira recorriendo por todas, por lo que tenemos que hacer otro foreach para obtener los datos de la foto `$value["file_id"]`.

```
foreach ($resultado['result']['photos'] as $clave => $valor){
    foreach($valor as $key => $value){
      echo $value["file_id"];
    }
}
```